# input type text onfocus function not calling

Tags: javascript, input, onfocus

I have a table where each td element will contain a input type text.

```
<tr>
    <td id="a1"><input type="text" id="a1t"/></td>
    <td id="a2"><input type="text" id="a2t"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="b1"><input type="text" id="b1t"/></td>
    <td id="b2"><input type="text" id="b2t"/></td>
</tr>
```

I need to know the td id when text input is focused. I tried doing that by calling a js function with onfocus event attached to input type text, but the function is not getting called.

```
<input type="text" id="b2t" onfocus="cell_clicked('b2t')" />
```

Here is the function and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywt8V/):

```
function cell_clicked(cell_no){
    alert(cell_no);
}
```

But the function is not getting called. 
Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: show us your `cell_clicked()`

Comment: can you share a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: hold on a sec will make the jsfiddle

Comment: you can use parent jquery http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: function cell_clicked(cell_no){
 console.log(cell_no);
}

Comment: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRL4H/) or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRL4H/1/)

Comment: works fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSQn2/1)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your function (it should work, *if* your browser has object console..). Please create a fiddle that replicates your problem.

Comment: there is no bug, your code absolutely works fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ywt8V/

Comment: any reason y my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ywt8V/4/) is not working?

Comment: @nkmol ur jsfiddle is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, you have a setting wrong in jsfiddle.
Under `Framework and extensions` change `onLoad` to `no wrap` to make your function `cell_clicked` globally available.

See this http://jsfiddle.net/ywt8V/3/ (your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ywt8V/ with just this setting is changed).

As a side-note, you could access the id of the parent table-cell like this:

```
onfocus="cell_clicked(this.parentNode.id)"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: but how do i make it work in my application.Ur answer solved the jsfiddle but application still fails to work.

Comment: Then.. using the correct settings in jsfiddle, provide a new fiddle, containing your live code. The code you have currently provided (in your question and fiddle) has been proven to work in multiple fiddles in this thread.

Comment: the code is working in jsfiddle on changing the settings.But in my app same code is not working..Infact,i copy pasted the code from my page source.

Comment: Then show us that code, there is no other way.. Something else (probably other code with an error) must be the problem.

Comment: chuck it all..Your "side-note" serves my end purpose..!! :) Thanks for the time..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<td><div id="boom" class="selected"><input type="text" id="b2t" onfocus="cell_clicked(this.id)" /></div></td>



function cell_clicked(id){
    var foo = $( "#"+id ).parent(".selected").attr( "id" );
    alert(foo);
}
```

Comment: not possible to add the input text selector as the structure is created dynamically